# Spring security addCorsMappings has no effect

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, cors

I'm using angular 5.0.5 and spring boot 2.0.2.RELEASE

angular is running on localhost:4200
spring is running on localhost:8181

trying to configure cors in the spring security so I enable cors in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(authorizedPaths).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

And I use `WebMvcConfigurer` for the cors configuration but even if I put fake origin and limit the `httpMethod` to only DELETE My angular app still has access to the backend and don't get rejected like I do not have any cors config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfigurerImpl implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://fake-domain.com")
                .allowedMethods("DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
                .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

even with postman, I can still use HTTP request to reach the backend
It's been a while trying to make it work before posting so I'm a bit desperate

Comment: Did below suggestion help you.?

Comment: Make sure that you do not have configured CORS at multiple places with different configuration in ymls, using annotation and CorsRegistry

Comment: I removed my WebMvcConfigurer, and I followed the suggested solution in the answer and the only config that I have now is CorsConfigurationSource, and still, even with fake origins, methods, and headers, everything is still reachable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **CorsConfigurationSource** bean  in the same class which extends **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(asList("HEAD",
            "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
    // setAllowCredentials(true) is important, otherwise:
    // The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    // setAllowedHeaders is important! Without it, OPTIONS preflight request
    // will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(
            asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                    "Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Please refer https://github.com/techiesantosh/taskmanager-service/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/web/taskmanager/config/TaskConfig.java

Comment: I followed the link and added the corsConfigurationSource and again with fake origins, limited methods and fake headers, and I still can access the backend and consume the web services. I wonder if the cors config is taken into account when the backend and frontend are in localhost